# Connecting to MySQL via bash script does not execute queries

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to connect to mysql on localhost via a Bash script.(On a Raspberry PI 3B+ Raspbian)

The connection seems to work but instead of showing the query results it displays some kind of mysql help page.
Which look like this:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for ... using readline 5.2
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysql client client-server client-mariadb
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults          Print the program argument list and exit.
...
```

```
#!/bin/bash
username="user"
passwort="1234"
mysql -u $username -p$passwort -e "show databases;"
```

How can i change the command to execute the given statement?

Comment: you are at least missing -h HOST where HOST your server address is.

Comment: thanks, i added it, but it makes no difference. I think localhost might be the default :)

Comment: did you test the connection with another client? is the port number 3306? I believe it doesn't open a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password has some characters that was interpreted by the shell , you must protect the password by quoting .

Example my password has a  ( space )

```
MyMac:~ e444$ u="root"
MyMac:~ e444$ p="1234 2"
MyMac:~ e444$ mysql -u$u -p$p -h 127.0.0.1 -e "show databases;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

received here a access denied , because the password sent was the `1234`

```
MyMac:~ e444$ mysql -u$u -p"$p" -h 127.0.0.1 -e "show databases;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

here protect the variable with `"`

Comment: Thanks a lot :), it works if I use the command without the Variables and instead add the login data in text